# java tetris: how to make a tetris piece move as 4 distinct tiles

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make the game tetris in Java as a fun side project.

My game board is a grid of tiles:

`grid = new Tile[height][width];`

And within the grid, I create a new Tile object: `activetile = new Tile(this,0, 0); //add new tile to "this" board`

Currently:

- I'm able to control a **single** tile- move it down, left and right

  ```
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
      int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
      if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
          checkBottomFull(0,4);
          collisionCheck(activetile.getX(),activetile.getY());
          checkEndGame(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY());

          activetile.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1); 
          System.out.println("coordinates: " + activetile.getX() + ", " + activetile.getY());

          repaint();
      } 
          ...right key and left key code omitted
  ```

  - As you can see from the keyPressed method, `checkBottomFull()` will clear bottom row if full, `collisionCheck()` will generate a new piece if block hits floor or another piece below, and `checkEndGame()` will end the game if block is stuck at the top.

[image]

---

**I'm struggling with the following:**

- To create an actual tetris piece, I was thinking I should just generate 3 other instances of Tile, and based on what piece it is (L, O, Bar, Z, etc), set their locations at the appropriate places according to activetile (the single tile I have control over), like so:

  ```
  if (piece == "Bar") {
      block2 = new Tile(this, activetile.getX(), activetile.getY());
      block3 = new Tile(this, activetile.getX()+2, activetile.getY());
      block4 = new Tile(this, activetile.getX()+3, activetile.getY());
  }
  ```

The problem with this is, my collision detection for `activetile` won't allow it to move appropriately because it will run into its other blocks. I tried to fix that in `keyPressed()` by setting the location of `block2, block3, block4` AFTER the activetile's new location has been set, like so: (so once `activetile` moves down, all the others are allowed to move down so they don't overlap)

```
        activetile.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1); 
        block2.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1); 
        block3.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1); 
        block4.setLocation(activetile.getX(), activetile.getY()+1);
```

This may work for going down, but it won't work for moving left or right because the tiles will overlap.

---

So, am I correctly creating a new instane of a `Bar` piece by generating new blocks like that? Is my thinking correct?

---

**executable**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyh26dfbmsvt5c8/my_tetris_test.jar

**link to source code zip**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kt3sl6qqo54amk/Tetris%20Two.rar

Thanks!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've uploaded a runnable jar to dropbox as well as the source code as a zip. can you try it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've read through it, and I think my exe achieves all of those things. It's okay if you don't want to look at it though.

Comment: *"I think my exe achieves all of those things"*  An SSCCE needs no 'executable' and if the code is an SSCCE it can be posted as an edit.

Comment: @AndrewThompson  Okay, I'm not sure how to rephrase the problem. I believe it's Short, I've identified clearly where my issue is- I'm struggling with the following: basically stating I'm not sure how to go about making several tiles move together as one piece as they will collide with each other. it's Self Contained because I've posted the code where the issue is, as well as compilable/runable code below... they can run it and see the results for themselves, that's why I've included it. It's Correct, and I've posted the example of what I've tried. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: An SSCCE is short enough to be *included in the question.*  No need for an external link or RAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the Polygon class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html 
There are methods provided that can test for collision (insideness) with points on another object. You can also use `translate(deltaX, deltaY)` to greatly simplify the "motion" of your objects.